# Trouble understanding algebra in proof

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

[image]

Can someone explain to me the step where the integral lower bound turns from n to 1? I was trying to read this proof and I am having trouble understanding that step.

Comment: This sort of thing really benefits from drawing a picture (which I haven't the means to now, but perhaps someone else will oblige): it really makes these interchangings of orders of integration much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue carefully as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^\infty{dx\over x^{s+1}}&
\stackrel{(1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty\int_m^{m+1}{dx\over x^{s+1}}\\&
\stackrel{(2)}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m\int_m^{m+1}{dx\over x^{s+1}}\\&
\stackrel{(3)}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty m\int_m^{m+1}{dx\over x^{s+1}}\\&
\stackrel{(4)}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \int_m^{m+1}{\lfloor x \rfloor dx\over x^{s+1}}\\&
\stackrel{(5)}=\int_1^\infty{\lfloor x \rfloor dx\over x^{s+1}}
\end{align}
$$
Equalities (1) and (5) are chopping the integral into pieces. Equality (2) is interchanging the order of summation. Equality (3) is simply saying that you're summing the same quantity $m$ times. Equality (4) is best understood by asking yourself "what value does $\lfloor x\rfloor$ take when $x$ is between $m$ and $m+1$?

Answer (score 2):

You're rearranging the sum and the integral.  Originally, you have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^\infty$$
and after the change, you have 
$$
\int_1^\infty\sum_{n\leq x}1.$$
The difference is that you're integrating over $1$ to $\infty$ but multiplying the integrand by the number of times it appears in the original sum.

More precisely, you could write:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^\infty=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=n}^\infty\int_m^{m+1}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^m\int_m^{m+1}.
$$
The last equality is because the number of times that you integrate $\int_m^{m+1}$ is exactly $m$ (for the $n$ values from $1$ to $m$), which generates the $\sum_{n\leq x}1$.

Comment: Okay I get the general idea but how do you show the last equality algebraically. I don't see how n gets restricted by x :S

Comment: Think of it like a change of variables in a double integral (this is really what's going on).  The first pair of sums corresponds to integrating above the line $y=x$ in vertical strips.  The second corresponds to the same integral with horizontal strips.  In this particular example, count the number of times that you integrate from $m$ to $m+1$ in the original sum.

Comment: Ahhh okay, now I understand it thank you very much.